# How to make a div that covers the all area of the screen except the area covered by a fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I am facing problem while making two divs side by side in a way that second div starts after the width of the first div. I don't want to use `overflow: hidden`, as i want to start the second after the first paragraph. This is what i want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: What do you have so far? Question without code will get it downvoted or closed.

Comment: If this top left element is fixed, then how would you want this to behave when the rest of the site content gets scrolled? Do you want part of the text to float above it full with, then have image and text next to it, and then full width text below again? There is no easy way to actually achieve that, that would probably require a lot of scripting magic, to split the content into different elements dynamically all the time.

Comment: The top left element should also scroll up as the page scrolls

Comment: it's pretty simple. Take a look at [CSS Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). 
Here's a [sample](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/ajNXOK) for you.

Comment: You need svg. A div won't do the job.

Comment: use bootstrap grid system for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you make `<div>` like you shown in the image. But I have a suggestion. Both the elements in the below div are rectangle. but the content behaves like you drawn.

You can look up CSS Basics [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

```css
div{
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}
.small{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .</div>
  <div class="big">Aenean euismod eros et erat pharetra, at elementum odio suscipit. Cras a enim quis diam molestie sollicitudin eget ac est. Proin porta turpis a massa porta laoreet. Fusce semper facilisis erat nec suscipit. Aliquam gravida quis dui sed aliquet. Ut consequat ullamcorper volutpat. Cras neque tortor, pharetra id condimentum nec, accumsan ac ipsum.

Etiam sit amet convallis ante. In pulvinar eu erat eu fringilla. Nam scelerisque eget ligula a blandit. Nullam eu tortor augue. Nulla at eros arcu. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque eget tincidunt massa. Sed dictum faucibus risus ac varius. Praesent aliquet erat tortor, sed lacinia metus fermentum non. Nulla vitae sapien dui. Vestibulum sed urna quis ex dictum scelerisque id ut erat. Cras efficitur ligula eu neque pellentesque, eget posuere lacus aliquet. Pellentesque interdum at sem vitae aliquet. Donec cursus, elit et varius viverra, urna erat commodo sem, ac congue erat augue eget ex. Suspendisse posuere sem at tempor faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat.

Curabitur aliquam feugiat tortor vitae blandit. Quisque faucibus urna arcu, sed rhoncus quam rutrum scelerisque. Aliquam pulvinar condimentum accumsan. Etiam lorem nibh, porta vitae mauris sit amet, egestas interdum lectus. Proin sit amet dolor purus. Nunc sed sem sed purus sagittis congue iaculis sed mauris. Donec pellentesque ut dolor rhoncus iaculis. Donec quis magna accumsan turpis convallis dignissim. Integer vel nisl accumsan, ultrices augue ut, placerat eros. Phasellus eu lacinia elit, nec maximus dui.
</div>
```